# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_ssh2.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_ssh2.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: apache, xampp, php-7.2, ssh2-exec

I am trying to use `php_ssh2.dll(thread safe version-1.1.2)` using `xampp` on `Apache Server` in `PHP 7.2` running on Windows 10. My `phpinfo()` shows `Compiler` is `MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017)`, `Architecture` is `x86` and `Thread Safe` is enabled. After downloading i kept `php_ssh2.dll` on `C:\xampp\php\ext` folder and also added `extension=php_ssh2.dll` to `php.ini` file. After that i restarted my Apache Server. But the problem isn't resolved. Some posts suggest to use `libssh2.dll` but failed to find that dll inside the `package(php_ssh2-1.1.2-7.1-ts-vc14-x86.zip)` I downloaded. Can anyone help me on this one? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP 7.2 you would need to use version compiled with VC15 compiler. Unfortunately it is not available for download at pecl.php.net, but you can download it from https://github.com/nufue/pecl-ssh2-windows